# IOS calling WCF service

Tags: wcf, ios, wsdl

I am trying to call a WCF service from IOS Xcode. I am generating the code from WSDL using SuDz-C. The code is successfully generated as far as the Exposed classes and methods are concerned. But, the Enums that are exposed from my WCF service are not generated in the code.

When i access this service from a .Net client all the classes,methods and enums are generated successfully. But the IOS client has Enums missing.

Can anyone help me out on how to get the Exposed Enum values from the WCF service.

Thanks

Comment: Are the enum properties generated at all?  For example, are they just generated as string or int properties?

Comment: The Enum types are not generated at all on Ios...whereas when i use a .net client to access the same service the enums are exposed correctly

Comment: It looks like SuDz-C is an alpha product so enums might not be supported yet.  Your best bet is likely to add the code for the enum properties manually to your generated proxy.